# Customizing default icons in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, customization

I am trying to find out how to change the default folder icon for all folder.

Obviously, I could go one by one, but that doesn't seem smart at all. 
Also - those I did change individually (The folders inside my home folder) Stayed with their original icons in the "Places" menu on the left. Is there any way of changing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Use a diffrent icon theme?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to change every single folder icon...then go to `/usr/share/icons` and then whatever icon theme you are using. Then you can copy & paste the icons you would like to use.

A much simpler alternative would be to google for an icon theme you like and installing it.

Comment: Right, but I couldn't find any Icon theme for unity

Comment: here is one I like for example http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/faenza-icon-theme-updated-adds-handful-of-new-icons/ to use it you need to have the gnome-tweak-tool installed after installing you have to set the icon theme from within gnome-tweak-tool.